# Is social media bad for the mental health of youth?

Tags: public-health, social-media

Multiple sources have blamed on social media for having (or potentially having) negative impact on mental state of young people. To name few:

[NPR](https://www.npr.org/2023/01/08/1147735477/seattles-schools-are-suing-tech-giants-for-harming-young-peoples-mental-health) writes

> SEATTLE — The public school district in Seattle has filed a novel lawsuit against the tech giants behind TikTok, Instagram, Facebook, YouTube and Snapchat, seeking to hold them accountable for the mental health crisis among youth.
> ...
> **It blames them for worsening mental health and behavioral disorders** including anxiety, depression, disordered eating and cyberbullying; making it more difficult to educate students; and forcing schools to take steps such as hiring additional mental health professionals, developing lesson plans about the effects of social media, and providing additional training to teachers.

[uclahealth.org](https://www.uclahealth.org/news/social-media-causing-psychological-harm-youth-and-young) writes

> **Social media can distort how people view themselves**, Dr. Thames explained. Sadly, many youths wrap their identity within the cloak of their standing on social media.

[Unicef.org](https://www.unicef.org/stories/social-media-bad-teens-mental-health) writes

> If you were born after 1995 then you won’t remember life before the Internet. Being connected through smartphones and social media is now just a part of growing up for many children and adolescents. Most of them have positive experiences online, but there are risks involved, **including whether the excessive use of social media can ultimately harm their mental health**. Research in this area is still in its early stages, but the significance of social media in the lives of many young people is clear.

- Is there evidence for negative impact of social media on mental health?
- If so, to what degree does the impact vary on young developing minds?

Comment: There is a video from Sabine about it that mentions several papers and their quality or lack of it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XDqESkPiV4E&pp=ygUTc2FiaW5lIHNvY2lhbCBtZWRpYQ%3D%3D

Comment: @Schmuddi Edited based on feedback. Second question is relevant as the sources specifically mention adolescence.

Comment: The question is very, very broad. It suffers from similar problems to [Is this food harmful?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3480/is-is-this-foodstuff-harmful-harmful). I have focused it on youth, because that's where the claims are focussed, but getting much more specific might help. Is it only about "excessive use" (which is a loaded term: of course "excessive use" is bad, because that is what "excessive" means.)

Comment: @Oddthinking Agreed. However, were the question to vary from the specific claim the question would be closed as it does not address the claim itself. (Which could be meta discussion in itself.) I already had to delete parts of question as they were not direct quotes.

Comment: Oh, agreed. We would need to find some specific claims - perhaps from the same sources. But lumping Instagram and Twitter, StackOverflow and 4Chan, Reddit and imgur in the same category, and occasional use versus obsessive use into the same category, and all mental health issues in the same category, is going to make drawing a single conclusion very difficult.

Comment: single data point, and I'm definitely not a youth and haven't been since before there was social media, but my mental health has improved a lot since abandoning social media.

Comment: @jwenting Noted. If it's working for you, keep it up.

Comment: @jwenting: So you don't consider Stack Exchange to be social media?

Comment: Sadly I don't have time to leave a proper answer, so I will leave this here for now: https://jonathanhaidt.substack.com/p/social-media-mental-illness-epidemic

Comment: @Oddthinking you seriously consider SE to be on the same level with twitter and facebook?

Comment: There's no consensus, this is still a hotly contested issue.

Comment: @jwenting: I seriously consider SE to satisfy all the definitions of Social Media I found via googling. It isn't the same "level" as Twitter and Facebook, but Twitter and Facebook are not on the same level as each other either, so we have the problem of the definitions being too broad to be meaningful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question is too broad, so the answer is "It depends".

---

- Sadagheyani, H.E. and Tatari, F. (2021), "[Investigating the role of social media on mental health](https://www.emerald.com/insight/content/doi/10.1108/MHSI-06-2020-0039/full/html)", Mental Health and Social Inclusion, Vol. 25 No. 1, pp. 41-51. DOI: 10.1108/MHSI-06-2020-0039

  This study was a systematic review that looked at the literature as of 2020:

  > The findings showed that social media has **negative and positive effects on mental health**. Negative effects included anxiety, depression, loneliness, poor sleep quality, poor mental health indicators, thoughts of self-harm and suicide, increased levels of psychological distress, cyber bullying, body image dissatisfaction, fear of missing out and decreased life satisfaction. Positive effects included accessing other people’s health experiences and expert health information, managing depression, emotional support and community building, expanding and strengthening offline networks and interactions, self-expression and self-identity, establish and maintain relationships.

---

- Berryman, C., Ferguson, C.J. & Negy, C. [Social Media Use and Mental Health among Young Adults](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11126-017-9535-6). Psychiatr Q 89, 307–314 (2018). DOI:10.1007/s11126-017-9535-6

  > Some studies have indicated that social media use may be tied to negative mental health outcomes, including suicidality, loneliness and decreased empathy. Other studies have not found evidence for harm, or have indicated that social media use may be beneficial for some individuals.

  This particular study showed:

  > **social media use was not predictive of impaired mental health functioning**. However, vaguebooking was predictive of suicidal ideation, suggesting this particular behavior could be a warning sign for serious issues. Overall, results from this study suggest that, with the exception of vaguebooking, concerns regarding social media use may be misplaced.

---

For balance, here is another study that showed that, as Facebook was rolled out in colleges, mental health declined:

- Braghieri, Luca, Ro'ee Levy, and Alexey Makarin. 2022. "[Social Media and Mental Health.](https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/aer.20211218)" American Economic Review, 112 (11): 3660-93. DOI: 10.1257/aer.20211218

  > We find that **the rollout of Facebook at a college had a negative impact on student mental health**. It also increased the likelihood with which students reported experiencing impairments to academic performance due to poor mental health. Additional evidence on mechanisms suggests the results are due to Facebook fostering unfavorable social comparisons.

(This was a "natural experiment", and I can't see how they accounted for exposure to social media increasing people's awareness of mental health issues, the relative health of their cohort and the available resources, and thus increased *reporting* of mental health issues without increasing the prevalence.)

---

Meanwhile adolescents *think* it is bad for mental health:

- Michelle O’Reilly et al, [Is social media bad for mental health and wellbeing? Exploring the perspectives of adolescents](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/1359104518775154)Clinical Child Psychology and Psychiatry, Volume 23, Issue 4 doi.org/10.1177/1359104518775154

  This 2018 study based on focus groups found:

  > Thematic analysis suggested that adolescents perceived social media as a threat to mental wellbeing and three themes were identified: (1) it was believed to cause mood and anxiety disorders for some adolescents, (2) it was viewed as a platform for cyberbullying and (3) the use of social media itself was often framed as a kind of ‘addiction’.

---

Maybe the negatives are outweighed by the positives - using social media programmes to educate people and improve their mental health.

Does that work? Cochrane has a systematic review on the subject. Short answer: No, the evidence doesn't support it!

- [Can programmes on social media help people to improve their health?](https://www.cochrane.org/CD012932/PUBHLTH_can-programmes-social-media-help-people-improve-their-health)

  > [Compared with non-interactive programmes, social media programmes] may have little to no effect on people's mental health, such as depression (evidence from 12 studies in 2070 people).

---

Mental health is a huge area. Youths and adolescents are a big group, covering a range of ages. Social media is a broad term.

There is no single answer to the question.

Comment: Latest development: Surgeon General 'we cannot conclude social media is sufficiently safe for children and adolescents' ref: https://www.hhs.gov/surgeongeneral/priorities/youth-mental-health/social-media/index.html Please consider adding this to answer.